# Is there any way to generate url alias instead of this taxonomy/term/%/faq, in views

Tags: views, 8

I have created a page view taxonomy/term/%/faq. It works fine but I need to replace taxonomy/term/% with its url alias.

Comment: Try using [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) which will help you create aliases for taxonomy pages.

Answer (score 3):

Pathauto just allows you to generate the URLs automatically so I believe you would still have the issue.

You will need something like https://www.drupal.org/project/path_alias_xt to extend the alias functionality to the other subpaths like the node/%/edit, taxonomy/term/%/faq etc.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto is another option.

Answer (score 0):

I did it that way : using [page_manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager) (with ui) & [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels), creating a panel page with an URL */taxonomy/term/%* and disabling (not deleting) default *taxonomy_term*  view (with its URL /taxonomy/term/% )

Then i copied default *taxonomy_term* view to a new one using different URL (different than */taxonomy/term/%*), i added a block (and disabled 'page' displayID) to this view acting exactly like default taxonomy_term view page.

**Note :** this block should have a contextual filter that correspond to taxonomy term ID (with depth or not)

Then i added this created block in my panel.

That allows to do what you are needing (get alias for URLs), and moreover, you can add things (blocks) to this page and it is a lot more flexible than overriding default *taxonomy_term* view. I did not this for that puprose, but you can get your goal this way.